# How to Call Array in Object by Javascript from API URL

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I try to call API from swapi,
I need to show title of films. I using jQuery to create it

here is my javascript

```
$(function(){
  function promiseTest(){
    return $.ajax({
      type: 'GET',
      url: 'https://swapi.co/api/people/',
    })
  }
  function promiseTest2(){
    return $.ajax({
      type: 'GET',
      url: 'https://swapi.co/api/films/', 
    })
}
var promise = promiseTest();
var promise2 = promiseTest2();

var bothPromise = $.when(promise, promise2);
bothPromise.done(function(data){
  $.each(data, function(i, name){
  $("#app").append("<ul><li>Name: "+ i.name +"</li><li>Height: "+name.height+" </li><li>Skin Color: "+ name.skin_color +"</li><li>Gender: "+name.gender+" </li><li>Film: "+ name.films.title +"</ul>")
})
})
```

HTML:

```
<div id="app"></div>
```

Here is my full code http://jsfiddle.net/dedi_wibisono17/phq7t50u/2/

I has try like [this code](http://jsfiddle.net/dedi_wibisono17/3datpcos/1/), but I want to show the title of films from https://swapi.co/api/films/.

Anybody help? Thank you

Comment: did you console the response and check?

Answer (score 1):

- The array of people is available in `data[0].results` - it doesn't exist in the base `data`.
- When you use jQuery `.each`, the first argument is the *iteration number*, not the item being iterated over. Give the function a second argument, and use it when specifying the names, heights, etc of the people:

```js
function promiseTest() {
  return $.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: 'https://swapi.co/api/people/',
  })
}

function promiseTest2() {
  return $.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: 'https://swapi.co/api/films/',
  })
}

var promise = promiseTest();
var promise2 = promiseTest2();

var bothPromise = $.when(promise, promise2);

bothPromise.done(function(data) {
  $.each(data[0].results, function(i, e) {
    $("#app").append("<ul><li>Name: " + e.name + "</li><li>Height: " + e.height + " </li><li>Skin Color: " + e.skin_color + "</li><li>Gender: " + e.gender + " </li><li>Film: " + e.films + "</ul>")
  })
  /*alert("done")*/
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

But there's no need for jQuery at all just for this - you can use `fetch` and `Promise.all`, which are supported natively in non-ancient browsers:

```js
Promise.all([
  fetch('https://swapi.co/api/people/').then(res => res.json()),
  fetch('https://swapi.co/api/films/').then(res => res.json())
]).then(data => {
  const app = document.querySelector('#app');
  data[0].results.forEach((e) => {
    app.innerHTML += "<ul><li>Name: " + e.name + "</li><li>Height: " + e.height + " </li><li>Skin Color: " + e.skin_color + "</li><li>Gender: " + e.gender + " </li><li>Film: " + e.films + "</ul>"
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

Comment: Ohh thanks for explain it. But how to I show:
Name : Luke Skywalker
....
Film : The Empire Strikes Back, Revenge of the Sith, Return of the Jedi, A New Hope, The Force Awakens

Not URL to show in frontend but the title of films from https://swapi.co/api/films/ any idea?

Comment: It looks like you'd have to make a separate `fetch` for each of said films in the films array, unless the API provides an easier way.